# Intellij IDEA opening File Type with External Tool

Tags: intellij-idea

I have Intellij IDEA 2016.2, and was trying to open a SVG with Inkscape from IDE, with a double-click.

I was only able to configure Inkscape as External Tool, and SVG as its own file type, since its handled as XML.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Register new file type. It's described in manual: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/opening-and-reopening-files-in-the-editor.html